# static method can't return struct type?(C++)

Tags: c++, methods, static, struct, return

I want to know what is doing wrong here:

```
class Grasp
{
    typedef struct
    {
        int unique;
        int intersection;
        int sets;
        float alpha;
        int *covered;
        int *choosen;
    }best;
    static best findSolution();
}
```

On .cpp:

```
best Grasp::findSolution()
{
    //it doesn't matter
}
```

There is an error on that line: **best** Grasp::findSolution()

'**best**' does not name a type

Why?

Comment: You're outside of the scope of the `Grasp` class, so the compiler can't see a symbol named `best`.

Comment: Did you try changing it to `Grasp::best`?

Comment: **As a sidenote, you dont need to use `typedef`. You could just write `struct best { ... }` in C++. That is preferred.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`best` is a *nested* type, as it is a *member* of `Grasp`. So you need to qualify the return type as:

```
Grasp::best Grasp::findSolution()
{
     //your code
}
```

Note the return type. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`best` is a typedef contained within `Grasp`. Unless it was global the compiler has no way of knowing it belonged to that class. Use `Grasp::best` instead:

```
Grasp::best Grasp::findSolution()
{
    // ..
}
```